# Chrome browser opens and closes using watir webdriver

Tags: selenium, watir, webdriver, watir-webdriver

I have the following code:

```
require "rubygems"
require "watir-webdriver"
browser = Watir::Browser.new(:chrome)
browser.goto "http://google.com"
```

When i run this code, the browser opens the site google.com and then closes automatically
Why does it close automatically? My chrome version is 12.0.742.68

Comment: OS (Windows, Mac, Linux...)? watir-webdriver version? Any error messages?

Comment: OS is Windows 7, Watir-webdriver 0.2.3, No error message is displayed. This is the only message that is displayed _Started ChromeDriver port=34882_

Comment: See this other SO thread from a little while ago, it sounds like the exact same sort of issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073559/how-do-i-prevent-watir-from-auto-closing-firefox

Comment: Also met this issue today.
OS: Windows
Browser: Chrome 12.0.742.112 Error msg:
Only "Started ChromeDriver port=29948" is displayed.

Comment: I suggest that you tag this with webdriver and/or selenium tags too, maybe webdriver/selenium people will be able to help.

Answer (score 3):

The Chrome driver will close all browser instances when your program exits. It's a [known issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=87676), and its priority was fortunately bumped today - look for a fix soon.