# Opening a browser in fullscreen mode using watir-webdriver

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I know this is a very silly question. Yet, am not able to find how to make the browser open in fullscreen mode using watir webdriver. i tried using maximize() but in vain. This is how the code looks like:

```
require "rubygems"
require "watir-webdriver"
ff = Watir::Browser.new(:firefox)
ff.goto("http://google.com")
ff.maximize()
```

getting the error "undefined method maximize"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know screen size, you can move the browser to the top left corner and set it's size to screen size: [Setting browser window size in Watir-webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6126311/setting-browser-window-size-in-watir-webdriver).

Comment: Thanks for replying. Trust me I posted this question only after seeing the post you've mentioned in your reply. And in fact, that is still there in the next tab of the browser :) I thought there would be some command like maximize() that would make the browser full mode

Comment: Y does this command **browser.execute_script('window.resizeTo(800,600)')** work in firefox but not in Chrome ?

Comment: Maybe there is, you should ask webdriver people. Add webdriver and/or selenium tag(s) to the question, or ask at their mailing list.

Comment: The browser (Chrome) is not getting resized to the size i mention. It stays in the default window size. No error message is displayed

Comment: could you pls provide ur feedback one this one too: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6176526/chrome-browser-opens-and-closes-using-watir-webdriver]

Comment: This is has been marked as WontFix in the Chromium tracker: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=2091

Comment: I'm not sure if something changed, but I have absolutely no issues using `browser.window.resize_to 1400, 1040` in chrome.

Answer (score 8):

Right now, it's possible to maximize the browser doing:

```
require "rubygems"
require "watir-webdriver"
browser = Watir::Browser.new(:firefox)
browser.goto("http://google.com")    
browser.driver.manage.window.maximize
```

Actually is going down to Selenium Driver to handle it, and AFAIK it works fine in Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me! You have to say `.window.maximize` instead of just `.maximize`

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new "firefox" 
browser.goto "http://example.com"
browser.window.maximize
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm using ruby+watir-webdriver and this code works for both Firefox and IE browsers 
(I have not checked in other browsers)

```
screen_width = browser.execute_script("return screen.width;")
screen_height = browser.execute_script("return screen.height;")
browser.driver.manage.window.resize_to(screen_width,screen_height)
browser.driver.manage.window.move_to(0,0)
```

Comment: For chrome, this is the only solution working for me on mac

Answer (score 4):

what worked for me is the following

in hooks.rb (if you are using cucumber)

```
Before do
    @browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox #( :chrome, :ie, etc)
    @browser.driver.manage.window.maximize
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the ruby code or watir, but for Chromedriver in selenium you cannot just call for the window to by maximized with the driver.manage().window().maximize();

Instead you have to do a neat little work around. You need to pass the option to the Chromedriver.  See this post [How to set Chrome preferences using Selenium Webdriver .NET binding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15824996/how-to-set-chrome-preferences-using-selenium-webdriver-net-binding)

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("-start-maximized");
//start the chromedriver 
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"*Path_To_Chromedriver*", options)

   //Perform your test

driver.Quit();
```

Comment: The latest versions of ChromeDriver do support the driver.manage().window().maximize call.

Comment: Using ChromeDriver v2.9 (2014-01-31) that supports Chrome v31-34 and cannot make the call.

Comment: Try updating your WebDriver to the latest version, because it is certainly working.  See https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=65&can=1&q=maximize&colspec=ID%20Status%20Pri%20Owner%20Summary

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me

```
@browser = Watir::Browser.new
@browser.goto("http://google.com")
@browser.driver.manage().window().maximize
```

Comment: Note that this is the same as existing answers - eg the [answer by @gonzalo](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12412460/1200545)