# How to set Chrome preferences using Selenium Webdriver .NET binding?

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Here is what I'm using, user agent can be successfully set, while download preferences cannot.

Windows 7, Chrome 26, Selenium-dotnet-2.31.2, chromedriver_win_26.0.1383.0

```c#
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
var prefs = new Dictionary<string, object> {
    { "download.default_directory", @"C:\code" },
    { "download.prompt_for_download", false }
};
chromeOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("chrome.prefs", prefs);
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--user-agent=" + "some safari agent");
var driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

Taken from chromedriver.log:

```
[1.201][FINE]:      Initializing session with capabilities {

   "browserName": "chrome",

   "chrome.prefs": {

      "download.default_directory": "C:\\code",

      "download.prompt_for_download": false

   },

   "chrome.switches": [ "--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/534.57.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version..." ],

   "chromeOptions": {

      "args": [ "--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/534.57.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version..." ],

      "binary": "",

      "extensions": [  ]

   },

   "javascriptEnabled": true,

   "platform": "WINDOWS",

   "version": ""

}
```

Check the temp Preferences file at `*temp\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences`, no `"default_directory"` and `"prompt_for_download"` are set.

```
   "download": {
      "directory_upgrade": true
   },
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The Selenium dotNet driver does not support setting the `chrome.prefs` out of the box. The problem is that `chrome.prefs` must be defined as `prefs` under the `chromeOptions` node. The `ChromeOptions` class does not contain this variable, so you'll need to create your own `ChromeOptions` class:

```
public class ChromeOptionsWithPrefs: ChromeOptions
{
    public Dictionary<string,object> prefs { get; set; }
}

public static void Initialize()
{
    var options = new ChromeOptionsWithPrefs();
    options.prefs = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "intl.accept_languages", "nl" }
    };
    _driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\path\chromedriver", options);
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you. How did you know this? Any references?

Comment: I learned from https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/wiki/CapabilitiesAndSwitches#List_of_recognized_capabilities that the prefs should be part of chromeOptions. Then I reverse-engineered the Selenium .NET driver with JetBrains dotPeek to see how it passed options to chromedriver.exe. Apparently ChromeOptions is quite literraly a wrapper around the chromeOptions-object chromedriver expects. The .NET library serializes the ChromeOptions to JSON and passes it to chromedriver. By inheriting from ChromeOptions and adding your own properties you can add more options :-)

Comment: Bravo, Martin! This worked wonderfully! A small disclaimer for readers, although .NET styling and consistency rules demand for Properties to be capitalized, do not capitalize the `prefs` property. Otherwise, the Chrome Driver will not be able to parse it correctly and will through an error upon being called.

Comment: For those who can't get this to work, see Ben's solution below.

Comment: If this answer no longer works, shouldn't it be removed, or flagged up?

Answer (score 33):

If you have updated to Chrome Version 36.0.x and Selenium 2.42, Martins solution no longer works.

It seems to have been updated. You now can use the following code

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddUserProfilePreference(string preferenceName, object preferenceValue);
```

I currently use it to change my Printer settings to "Save as PDF" instead of the default using this code as an example

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddUserProfilePreference("printing.print_preview_sticky_settings.appState", "{\"version\":2,\"isGcpPromoDismissed\":false,\"selectedDestinationId\":\"Save as PDF\");
```

I thought Martin's solution was very good and accurate, but it suddenly stopped working for me, so naturally I had to see if I could find a solution.

Comment: This works like a charm for latest chrome. You make my day.. :)