# Download MP4 file instead of playing it using ChromeDriver?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, chrome-web-driver

I'm using Chrome Web Driver 2.10 [chromedriver_win32.zip](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.10/) with [Selenium WebDriver 2.31.2](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver/2.31.2).

With verbose logging enabled it seems the **DesiredCapabilities** (https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities) are passed just fine,

```
[1.174][FINE]:      Initializing session with capabilities {

   "browserName": "chrome",

   "chrome.switches": [  ],

   "chromeOptions": {

      "args": [  ],

      "binary": "",

      "extensions": [  ],

      "prefs": {

         "download.default_directory": "C:\\Downloads",

         "download.directory_upgrade": "true",

         "download.extensions_to_open": "",

         "download.prompt_for_download": "false"

      }

   },

   "javascriptEnabled": true,

   "platform": "WINDOWS",

   "version": ""

}
```

but Chrome Web Driver is playing ***.mp4** instead of downloading.

I've tried the solution at [How to set Chrome preferences using Selenium Webdriver .NET binding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15824996/how-to-set-chrome-preferences-using-selenium-webdriver-net-binding) but it doesn't seem to work with newer Chrome Web Driver version, and it crashes if i try and use [selenium-dotnet-2.31.2](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/detail?name=selenium-dotnet-2.31.2.zip) with [chromedriver_win_26.0.1383.0](https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/detail?name=chromedriver_win_26.0.1383.0.zip).

Anybody has a suggestion?

Comment: Try to ensure the download directory exists. I had a mistake where the directory didn't exist and Chrome would pop up a dialog asking where to save.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```java
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
prefs.put("download.default_directory", getClass().getResource("/data/input").toString().replace("%20", " ").replace("file:","").replaceFirst("/", ""));
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);

options.addArguments("--test-type");
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
```

Comment: "getClass().getResource("/data/input").toString().replace("%20", " ").replace("file:","").replaceFirst("/", "")" is a path to maven target/data/input

Answer (score 3):

I got this working by below code:

```java
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chromedriver");
String downloadFilepath = "/path/to/download";
HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadFilepath);
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
HashMap<String, Object> chromeOptionsMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
options.setExperimentalOptions("prefs", chromePrefs);
options.addArguments("--test-type");
DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptionsMap);
cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(cap);
```

Answer (score -5):

This worked greatly for me:

```
DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();

FirefoxProfile fprofile= new FirefoxProfile();
fprofile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList",2);  //0-desktop,1-file download folder,2-specified location
fprofile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false); //prevent download file window
fprofile.setPreference("browser.download.dir","E:\\Downloadfilebyprogram");
fprofile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.focusWhenStarting", false);
//fprofile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false);
//fprofile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone", true);
//fprofile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.useWindow", false);
//fprofile.setPreference("services.sync.prefs.sync.browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
//fprofile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile,","application/vnd.ms-excel");
fprofile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","application/vnd.ms-excel");
fprofile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.alertOnExeOpen", false); //prevent from opening a file

cap.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, fprofile);
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver(cap);
```

Comment: The issue was to do with Chrome, not Firefox.