# Set default printer and directory for PDF printing in ChromeDriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I use `Selenium WebDriver` to print pages to PDF with `Robot` class. There are multiple PDF printers installed. I try to set default directory with code:

```
HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", mydownloadDirectory);
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

To set built-in PDF printer as default could be set by this code, but I don't want to disable all the extension.

```
options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15824996/how-to-set-chrome-preferences-using-selenium-webdriver-net-binding might be that will help

Comment: @Dhru'soni : I tried to use this: `options.AddUserProfilePreference("printing.print_preview_sticky_settings.appState", "{\"version\":2,\"isGcpPromoDismissed\":false,\"selectedDestinationId\":\"Save as PDF\");` , but doesn't solved this problem.